# UIActivityView doesn't display other apps as option to open pdf

Tags: iphone, ios, pdf, uiactivityviewcontroller

I'm displaying a PDF in my app and I want to have to same "openIn" functionality as the default iOS mail client.

The code I have is as follows:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"/var/mobile/Applications/21D850EA-409A-4231-BDFE-6B79FC721DA3/Library/Caches/1373665423163257247920130712/84cd7f88cf1b400cb1f4a4d6ac439649.pdf"];    
UIActivityViewController *activityViewController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:@[url] applicationActivities:nil];
[self presentViewController:activityViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

I've hard coded the path for testing.
The first image below is how it looks in the mail client.
The second image is how it looks in my app.

Any help would be great.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You misunderstand what is happening. In the Mail app you have opened the PDF in the preview window. The actions icon then brings up a `UIDocumentInteractionController` with the standard "options" menu.

The `UIActivityController` does not provide any "open in" functionality. If your want the same options in your app as from the Mail attachment preview window, use a `UIDocumentInteractionController` and use one of the `presentOptionsMenu...` methods.